# Getting GarageBand after restoring MacBook

Tags: garageband

So I recently purchased a MacBook Air. I had initially set it up without an Apple ID, and I saw GarageBand on my machine. I had to reset the MacBook for certain reasons afterwards, so I erased the hard drive and reinstalled macOS High Sierra.

However, when I set up the Mac after it was reset, GarageBand was not there. Is there any way to bring it back? I had not redeemed GarageBand at any point of time.

Comment: GarageBand is free.  Just go to the [App store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/garageband/id682658836?mt=12&ls=1) and download it.